# Is $\frac{1}{e^{\beta(E-\mu)}}= \frac{e^{\beta E_k}}{\sum_{k=1}e^{-\beta E_k}}$?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I was reading a Quantum fluids book, in the introduction say that the Boltzmann Distribution is:

$\frac{1}{e^{\beta(E-\mu)}}$

but I don't understand the relation between the Boltzmann distribution that I Know:

$\frac{e^{\beta E_k}}{\sum_{k=1}e^{-\beta E_k}}$

Comment: I think you probably mean $\frac{1}{e^{(E-\mu)/k_BT}}=e^{-\beta(E-\mu)}$

Comment: The LHS is the expected number of particles that have energy $E$ in the grand canonical ensemble. The RHS is the probability of the $k$-th energy level being occupied in the canonical ensemble.